# ArcPro Data Update

Tags: esri, arcmap

I'm getting some contradictory information about this. I have an ArcPro project. In that project, I connected to a desktop MS Access database and pulled in a table. I then pulled the table into the contents of the map and used it to make a layer. When I made the layer, I scheduled a refresh of the layer; however, does that automatically schedule a refresh of the source table? E.g. Will it automatically re-pull that data from MS Access and then create a new layer? Or will it just be recreating the layers based on old data from when I initially added the table?